# Breaking up list with unnecessary characters into smaller list

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have a list called **error** (in python) that is as follows :

error[0] = ['a','cat','yes']

error[1] = ['b','dog','yes']

error[2] = ['c','cat','yes']

How can I remove the brackets and make each index of the original list, a list by itself for example

errlist1 = [a,cat,yes]

errlist2 = [b,dog,yes]

errlist3 = [c,cat,yes]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: May be unpacking it by ``errlist1, errlist2, errlist3 = error`` if `error` is a list of list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```py
errlist1  = [",".join(error[0])]
errlist2  = [",".join(error[1])]
...
```

Comment: @Anrich great - consider validating the answer then - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store the values in the list as a list on their own?

```
errlist1 = error[0]
errlist2 = error[1]
```

etc.

Comment: yes, sorry if I was not descriptive enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for list out lists, then,

```
>>> error = []
>>> error.append(['a','cat','yes'])
>>> error.append(['b','dog','yes'])
>>> error.append(['c','cat','yes'])
>>> error
[['a', 'cat', 'yes'], ['b', 'dog', 'yes'], ['c', 'cat', 'yes']]
>>>
```